# Method Not Executing in a Synchronous Manner

Tags: java, model-view-controller

I have a MVC-based Java application which I am building, and there is a particular method within my controller (shown below) which behaves as follows:

- The model is updated via the initialize method, as I would intend.
- The update to the view is not occurring because the `model.start()` method never terminates (since it is an infinite while loop).

I want to have my view to update first, and then be able to `start()` my model.  How do I alter my code to get the desired behavior?

I suppose one workaround would be replace the `model.start()` line with code that fires an event which my model is able to observe, but I have not tried that yet, because I want to understand the source of my problem.

Also, I have no idea if this is relevant, but my main application class defines a separate thread for my swing components via `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()...`, and my view is made up of swing components.  There may be some issue related to multiple threads executing, and if so, that would explain why my `initializedPerformed()` method is not executing in a synchronous way.

**Method in the controller which does not behave like I expect/want:**

```
public void initializePerformed(Event e) {
    model.initialize(e);
    view.getPanel().setName(model.getName());
    model.start();
}
```

**model.start():**

```
public void start() {
    while (true) {

    }
}
```

Comment: What code is updating the view?

Comment: Just a simple method for setting the text of a JPanel, `setText()`.  If I comment out the code for `model.start()`, my JPanel updates just like I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need `model.start()` at all, which I highly doubt you do, then start it in a separate thread like this:

```
new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        model.start();
    }
}
```

If `model` is actually inheriting from `Thread`, then you shouldn't be overriding `start()` at all. You should override `run()`, which is called after `Thread.start()`, and after the new thread has actually been created. If you override `start()`, no new threads will be created.

Comment: `model.start()` is basically my first attempt at defining a game loop.  I have never worked with game loops before, and I have never tried to work them in with the MVC design pattern.  The game is very simple, but `start()` is the start of the game loop.  I have never declared a separate thread before, but perhaps that is the correct thing to do for a game loop and/or game state.

Comment: After doing a bit more research, it seems as though I should be creating a `SwingWorker` thread to represent my model.  Would you agree?

Comment: No. Instead, you should put data field inside your model and methods to change them, and have the controller update the model and the view when needed. the view gets the data from teh model

Comment: I think a model can be a legitimate source of events--to which the view can listen and off of which it can base its updates.  Say you had timers in the model, or you had calculations based off of some AI/bot.  All of that should be stored within the model, and the view can directly listen to events.  In such an example, the controller would be completely bypassed.  Anyway, to avoid problems like I am describing in my original post, turning the model into its own thread (via a `SwingWorker`) would help get around the GUI freezing issue.

Comment: I don't think the model should have it's own thread. For a timer, you can use a `javax.swing.Timer`. Events would only happen if fired by a timer or by calling a method. As for the AI/bots, they should be in their own thread. The point is, a model should not have it's own thread, but it should have threads for tasks it needs to preform.

Comment: If my model represent a game state, which it does, and I want to have a game loop, which I think I do, wouldn't that game loop be considered a "long-running" process?  And if so, isn't that what the `SwingWorker` is intended to address?  I was envisioning my game loop being a "long-running" process, but perhaps it shouldn't be or isn't.

Answer (score 0):

From what I remember about swing, all operations must be done by the "main" app thread (I forgot the technical name of it).

The pattern is : create threads to process your data, and leave the main thread only for display. When there is an event that should be displayed, notify the view but let the main thread change it (typically use the semaphore pattern, but if you find it too complex, you can also have an infinite loop that looks what's new each 100 ms for example and calls wait() to check again: business threads will change variables accessible to the main thread.

Best Regards,
Zied Hamdi
http://1vu.fr